# compare a NSNumber with a fixed value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a better way to compare a NSNumber with a fixed value, it just feels a little clunky.

```
if([myNumber isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) NSLog(@"Zero");
```

I do know I can use -compare but it pretty much looks the same ...

gary

Comment: Everything in Obj-C feels a little clunky for a while.

Comment: Using literals, it's not quite so bad: `[NSNumber isEqualToNumber:@0]`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

How about `if ([myNumber intValue] == 0)` ? (or < or >, obviously).

Comment: I'd note that this only works if the number is known to be an integer. the intValue of an NSNumber with the value 0.4 will be 0.

Answer (score 5):

`NSNumber` objects can contain ints, float, doubles etc.
Ben's approach (comparing to a `NSNumber`'s `intValue`) is very fast and easy to read, but it only works correctly if you can guarantee that `myNumber` is always in the range of an `int` (and always will be, even after future code changes).

For this reason, your approach is actually superior if you don't know the exact type of `myNumber`.

```
// This will work regardless if myNumber is an int, double etc.
[myNumber isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]
```

If comparing to larger fixed numbers or floats, you'll have to go this route anyway.
Also, recent versions of Xcode will properly warn you if you try to create a NSNumber with the wrong type, which can help spot problems early:

[image: Xcode 6.1.3 implicit conversion warning NSNumber]

Comment: Another subtle source of bug would be the subclass `NSDecimalNumber` that can produce wrong results from `intValue`. +1