# React Native 0.40.0: Ordered comparison between pointer and zero ('NSNumber *' and 'int')

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, react-native

I have a React Native project that is still on `0.40.0` and when I try to build in XCode for Simulator:

`Ordered comparison between pointer and zero ('NSNumber *' and 'int')`

It's in the file `RCTJavaScriptLoader.mm` in `React.xcodeproj` > `React` > `Base`

Because this error happens in a React Native file I have no idea what it is trying to tell me. The code block is:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
  NSMutableString *desc = [NSMutableString new];
  [desc appendString:_status ?: @"Loading"];

  if (_total > 0) { // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    [desc appendFormat:@" %ld%% (%@/%@)", (long)(100 * [_done integerValue] / [_total integerValue]), _done, _total];
  }
  [desc appendString:@"\u2026"];
  return desc;
}
```

I have tried to clean the project, I even deleted the ios folder and regenerated it by using `react-native upgrade` and it didn't help after I linked everything.

Comment: `if (_total > 0)` => `if ([_total integerValue]>0)` Because `_total` is a `NSNumber`, so you can't do `if (myNumber > 0)`, it doesn't make sense. As you did to do the division, use `integerValue`, or `floatValue`, etc.).

Comment: @Larme It's true what you're saying but this is library code of React Native, nothing I wrote, that's why it is strange to me and the error might be more react native related

Comment: If you look at the current version, it's fixed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.mm since 3 juan: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7123618aa863ab384d4091c52e9362a9afbbdec1#diff-94a4754d8421c7f4583bc5be41fcc77e on v0.51.0-rc.3 version. So I'd upgrade your version. Possible solution could be to subclass it, and override/write your own `description`, and call only your version, but that's a guess (inner calls could call it).

Comment: @Larme strange that it just appears now because that app is working for over a year now but I'll try to update the project, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explanation on the issue:
`if (_total > 0)` => `if ([_total integerValue] > 0)` because `_total` is a `NSNumber`. [Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428165/compare-a-nsnumber-with-a-fixed-value).

For the rest, it's an issue on [React-Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) that have been fixed since the 3th of January on that [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7123618aa863ab384d4091c52e9362a9afbbdec1#diff-94a4754d8421c7f4583bc5be41fcc77e).
According to the commit, it should be then fixed on version >= v0.51.0-rc.3 and it still fixed on [the current version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTJavaScriptLoader.mm) (no regression).

The recommendation is then to update your React version.

Comment: Bang on. It appears that this commit was added as early as 0.41.0 as well (maybe backported)? https://www.dropbox.com/s/k76kqznsjf1pyb1/Screen%20Shot%202019-04-07%20at%2011.11.39%20AM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with old versions of React Native and XCode 9.3 and it was fixed on [7123618a](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7123618aa863ab384d4091c52e9362a9afbbdec1#diff-94a4754d8421c7f4583bc5be41fcc77e)

Either upgrade your react native app to version great than ~0.51.0 or downgrade XCode to version lower equal than ~9.2